# Checksum field of a packet, should it be at head or tail?

Tags: c, embedded, protocols

I'm working on a small project that communicates with a FPGA board. It sends data to FPGA and sometimes the FPGA will send data back. So my colleague and I are going to design a simple communication protocol.

We decide to add a checksum field to our protocol. But we have different ideas about where to put it. I suggest putting it at the head of a packet and he prefers putting it at tail.

To put it in code, here is my suggestion:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint16_t frame_type;
    uint16_t length;
    uint16_t checksum;
    uint8_t data[];
}blah_blah;
```

And here is his:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint16_t frame_type;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t data[];  //let's assume it is a valid syntax
    uint16_t checksum;  
}blah_blah;
```

My point is that I can declare the struct easily and directly cast the last data field to another struct that I want, iff the variable length part is at the end of the packet. And his argument is FPGA reads and writes data by clock, so it's more convenient to update checksum each clock and finally put or check it at the end of the packet.

My knowledge about digital design is very limited, so I don't know which one is a better idea. Where should I put the checksum field?

Edit: Somebody reminds me about strict aliasing when casting a pointer. Even if I use `memcpy` to avoid casting, it is still easier for me to get checksum in the head. If the checksum is in the tail then I have to cast the buffer to a `const char*` then add the length offset and then cast it to a `const uint16_t*` to get it.

Comment: `uint8_t data[];  //let's assume it is a valid syntax` - but it is not. What is the actual suggestion?

Comment: In my experience, acquiesce to the firmware guys. What they do is harder than us software folk. Software is more malleable, debuggable, and changeable, although that could just be based on my inexperience with firmware. Furthermore, your "cast the last data field to another struct" comment has me concerned you're forgetting about [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: For what it's worth I've never seen a protocol with a checksum where it wasn't at the end of the packet.

Comment: @SergeyA `uint8_t data[];` _is_ valid in a `struct` _if_ it's the _last_ field in the struct.

Comment: @CraigEstey but in OP's second example it is explicitly NOT the last member.

Comment: If you have fixed size data, then you can do: `uint8_t data[256];` and put it anywhere. However, the usual for variable length payload/data is to _not_ have a checksum field in the `struct`, but append a checksum at the end in the message you send. Apply the checksum algorithm to _everything_ in the message (_including_ the checksum). If the resulting checksum is zero, the message is valid. That is, the message buffer is: `struct|data|csum` and `checksum(buffer)` should return 0.

Comment: @SergeyA OP's [first] example is okay. It is OP's "friend" that suggested the erroneous usage.

Comment: @CraigEstey this is exactly what I am trying to convey.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError TCP checksum is at the head of a packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Except for the fact that `uint8_t data[];` *must* be at the end of the `struct`.

Thus, as I suggested above, don't put the checksum *inside* the `struct`. You could even leave the `data` out of the `struct` [or not].

As I suggested in my top comment, a *buffer* could look like:

```
struct|data|csum
```

And, checksumming *all* of that, could sum to zero if the packet is valid.

---

Here's some sample code for one way that I've seen used (e.g. SDLC, etc.). It is crude and only checks some errors. It allow for the data payload to be in a different buffer.

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint16_t frame_type;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t data[];
} blah_blah;

#define CSUMSEED        0x1234
#define MAGIC           0xDEADBEEF

uint16_t
calcsum(uint16_t csum,const void *ptr,uint16_t length)
{

    uint8_t *data = ptr;
    for (;  length != 0;  --length, ++data)
        csum += *data;

    return csum;
}

void
sendone(int socket,uint16_t type,const void *data,uint16_t length)
{
    blah_blah hdr;

    uint16_t csum = CSUMSEED;

    hdr.magic_number = MAGIC;
    hdr.frame_type = type;
    hdr.length = length;

    csum = calcsum(csum,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    csum = calcsum(csum,data,length);

    // convert csum to "inverse" ???
    csum = ~csum;

    // could use writev here instead ...
    write(socket,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    write(socket,data,length);
    write(socket,&csum,sizeof(csum));
}

void
recvone(int socket,blah_blah *hdr,void *data)
// data -- must be large enough to hold _maximum_ payload
{

    uint16_t csum = CSUMSEED;
    ssize_t length;

    // get the header struct
    length = read(socket,hdr,sizeof(*hdr));
    if (length != sizeof(*hdr))
        error();

    // magic number must match
    if (hdr.magic != MAGIC)
        error()

    // get checksum for header
    csum = calcsum(csum,hdr,sizeof(*hdr));

    // get the data
    length = read(socket,data,hdr->length + sizeof(uint16_t));
    if (length != (hdr->length + sizeof(uint16_t))
        error();

    // get remaining checksum (including the trailing/appended CRC)
    csum = calcsum(data,data,length);
    if (csum != 0)
        error();
}
```

You could adapt this to embed the data at the end of the struct if you wish [as shown in the `struct` definition] with some slight modifications.

---

Here's a slight modification that appends the checksum. The receiver compares the checksum gotten from `read` with the calculated checksum:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint16_t frame_type;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t data[];
} blah_blah;

#define CSUMSEED        0x1234
#define MAGIC           0xDEADBEEF

uint16_t
calcsum(uint16_t csum,const void *ptr,uint16_t length)
{

    uint8_t *data = ptr;
    for (;  length != 0;  --length, ++data)
        csum += *data;

    return csum;
}

void
sendone(int socket,uint16_t type,const void *data,uint16_t length)
{
    blah_blah hdr;

    uint16_t csum = CSUMSEED;

    hdr.magic_number = MAGIC;
    hdr.frame_type = type;
    hdr.length = length;

    csum = calcsum(csum,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    csum = calcsum(csum,data,length);

    // could use writev here instead ...
    write(socket,&hdr,sizeof(hdr));
    write(socket,data,length);
    write(socket,&csum,sizeof(csum));
}

void
recvone(int socket,blah_blah *hdr,void *data)
// data -- must be large enough to hold _maximum_ payload
{

    uint16_t csum = CSUMSEED;
    ssize_t length;

    // get the header struct
    length = read(socket,hdr,sizeof(*hdr));
    if (length != sizeof(*hdr))
        error();

    // magic number must match
    if (hdr.magic != MAGIC)
        error()

    // get checksum for header
    csum = calcsum(csum,hdr,sizeof(*hdr));

    // get the data
    length = read(socket,data,hdr->length);
    if (length != hdr->length)
        error();

    // get data checksum
    csum = calcsum(data,data,length);

    // get message checksum
    uint16_t csum2;
    length = read(socket,&csum2,sizeof(csum2));
    if (length != sizeof(csum2))
        error();

    // validate the checksum
    if (csum2 != csum)
        error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the embedded device, it depends on the hardware.   If you're doing it a byte at a time via interrupts, probably better at the end.  (you calculate it as you go reading/writing RX/TX registers and then tack it on, or check it, depending on whether you're reading or writing.)

If its DMA driven and two separate blocks, or only one of it is DMA driven, then it probably doesn't matter.  You'll end up calculating the checksum/crc after all the data has reached you.

For the FPGA, however, it's almost certainly easier for them to 'tack on' the checksum at the end after the last byte has gone out, rather than pre-calculate the checksum on the packet, then insert it in the middle, then send out the data.